# HP Probook 4530s overheating problem (ati/radeon)

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, hybrid

Well, this is a painful topic, because I see, that graphic card developers don't want to support Linux environment with their drivers.

I have HP Probook i5-2430M CPU, ATI Radeon HD 6490M/ Intel HD Graphics 3000 and 4GB of RAM.

I tried different drivers but when i do simple tasks, my PC is overheating and CPU temperature goes between 70-80 degrees Celsius. While working on Windows, nothing gets hot while doing the same tasks.

Has anyone found any solution for this? I assume that switching to Intel Graphics could reduce the temperature, but then my Radeon gets useless and thats no good.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems with this model of laptop and I found that if you install "**Linux Mint 13 KDE Maya 64 bit**" (get *.iso from their website) and RADEON video driver **amd-driver-installer-12-6-x86.x86_64.run** (search for it on AMD website) everything will be **OK**!! You will have ~4h of battery and fan will even stop sometimes, and you can change between the dedicated RADEON card and Intel card using the amd ccle and then log out/log in.

I would post an image with a screenshot of my desktop to show you that this setup works, but I don't have 10 reputation points ...

Newer drivers from AMD don't work with latest Ubuntu 12.10 because Ubuntu has the latest version of Xorg/Xserver which is not supported **yet** by AMD drivers (read the release notes). So, in order to have a working setup you need a Linux distribution which has a compatible version of X.Org with the driver you need to install. Linux mint 13 has  X.Org 7.6 which is compatible with RADEON driver 12.6 which "knows" 7.6 (read the release notes).

TIPS: 
1) Never install updates in Linux Mint after you installed the AMD driver 12.6.
One day I installed updates and laptop got stuck at a black screen during boot.

2) To enable/disable "3D effects" in KDE press "Alt + Shift F12" this will improve FPS in games and maximize battery life. Minecraft works fine on Linux Mint (around 60 fps? if I remember well).

3) If somebody needs help on how to install AMD drivers, they can find working instructions [HERE](http://editpc.blogspot.ro/2012/10/hp-4530s-ubuntu-12041-desktop-amd64.html) which I wrote.

4) Linux Mint Maya is LTS and has support until 2017, plus it is fully compatible with all Ubuntu applications.

Comment: user52985, are you talking about AMD related updates, that are not advised to update, or you taling about any updates?