# Why does my HP ProBook 4530s get much hotter?

Tags: ati, graphics

my laptop details :-

> hp probook 4530 s
>   processor : Intel (R) core (TM) i7-2670 QM - cpu @ 2.20 GHZ (8cpus),~ 2.2 GHZ
>   memory 8192 MB RAM

about display card (VGA) :

> device name : mobile intel (R) HD graphics
>   manufacture : ATI technologies Inc.
>   chip type : intel(R) HD graphics family
>   DAC type : internal
>   approx.total memory : 779 MB
>   monitor : Generic pnp monitor

about Hard disc

> Hitach HTs547564AgE384 ATA Device

about Ubuntu 12.10 installation 
i installed ubuntu 12.10 from usb

> ubuntu 12.10 64 bit
>   ubuntu partition size on my hard disc = 30 Gb

i don't make "linux swap" during installation, because memory size (RAM) = 8GB
I already installed Windows 7 - 64 bit.. and choose linux or windows to boot

the problem is : 
the fan works loudly after booting ubuntu and during working with ubuntu ,, unlike using widows in the same conditions ( i mean same room temp. , not running a big process) ...

i installed "jupiter" for handling this problem ,, and also no big improvment ... 
the processor temp. starts about 40 deg. Celsius after 10 min it becomes about 53 celsius without running a heavy process .
what shall i do ?

finally some times when shutting down ubuntu ,, not work properly !
and don't closed !
appear on the screen a message i don't remember it now but i think 
" terminate all running process ... " and ubuntu still working without shutting down !
it occurs about 70% times i use ubuntu after the processor temp = 65 degrees

Answer (score 0):

I have same laptop and HP laptop got problem with Ubuntu!

1. [Install graphic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI) card from ATI site. And goto catalyst control center. goto swichable graphics. and select power saving GPU for improved battery life. worked for me.
2. I find [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2034773)  post and update your bios maybe help you. If NOT, try other desktop. Like Cinammon or Xfce or KDE. Folow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251083/hp-probook-4530s-overheating-problem-ati-radeon).